# What Excel formula can I use to total up bookings for each month in different years?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that can track all bookings and the total of each booking.

For example, I may do a booking in January 2022, but the booking doesn't take place until January 2023. Therefore the income doesn't come in until 2023, so the sheet should display that in 2023 money will be coming in.

What formula can I use that would automatically add up all totals between a certain date period?

I've attached screenshots of an example

[The Main Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNb3R.png)

[The Total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sHkv.png)

Each month needs to automatically total up any 'bookings' when data is entered that have happened in that month.

For example:

January 2022 - the total should read £20,000
February 2022 - the total should read £25,000
and so on

Answer (score 0):

[Image how it'd look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxu1M.png). After you just need to change format of cells with dates to only display month ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIu3M.png)), and you're done.

The formula used is

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10,">="&DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2),1),$A$2:$A$10,"<="&EOMONTH(D2,0))
```

where B2:B10 is your list of dates when booking happens, A2:A10 is price and D2 is cell where your target month/year is.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @JJ0911 please don't forget to mark it as an answer :)